# Почему у меня значение Current Asia Population выдается с буквой Е,да и вообще неправильно?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
package casting02;

public class Casting02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                
        
        long currentWorldPop = 7_000_000_000L;
        System.out.println("Current World Population: " +currentWorldPop);
        
        //World population in 1950,  Source: United Nations Population Division
        //2.52 Billion
        int africaPop   =   221_000_000;
        long asiaPop     =  1_402_000_000;
        int europePop   =   547_000_000;
        int americasPop =   339_000_000;
        int oceanaPop   =    13_000_000;
        System.out.println("World Population in 1950: " 
                +(africaPop +asiaPop +europePop +americasPop +oceanaPop));
        
        //The current population of Asia is an estimated 60% of the world population
        double percentAsia = (float)0.6;
        double currentAsiaPop  =currentWorldPop * percentAsia;
        System.out.println("Current Asia Population: " +currentAsiaPop);      
       
    }  
}
```

---

Все заработало,когда я изменил строчку таким образом

```
long currentAsiaPop = (long)(currentWorldPop * percentAsia);
```

Кто-нибудь может объяснить как так получилось?

Comment: [Экспоненциальная запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

Comment: Как исправить ?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте BigDecimal, вот пример:

```
long currentWorldPop = 7_000_000_000L;
BigDecimal percentAsia = new BigDecimal("0.6");
BigDecimal currentAsiaPop  = percentAsia.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(currentWorldPop));
System.out.println("Current Asia Population: " + currentAsiaPop);
```

Или

```
long currentWorldPop = 7_000_000_000L;
double percentAsia = 0.6D;
double currentAsiaPop  = currentWorldPop * percentAsia;
System.out.println("Current Asia Population: " + new DecimalFormat("#").format(currentAsiaPop));
```

Неправильно считалось, потому что вы при определении percentAsia делали приведение типов, в этом случае теряется точность.

Comment: Без него никак?

Answer (score 0):

Можно выводить через `System.out.printf`:

```
System.out.printf("Current Asia Population: %.2f\n", currentAsiaPop);
```

Вместо `%.2f` при выводе подставится ваше число, в данном случае выведется в формате с точкой с 2 знаками после точки (например, `4200000166.89`).

Другой вариант, форматировать строку с помощью класса `MessageFormat`:

```
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Current Asia Population: {0, number, #.##}", currentAsiaPop));
```

Вывод будет аналогичный.